# can i add new HTML element(eg. radio, checkbox,dropdown) to current a file on form submission?

Tags: php, html

i have one file which contains two fileds both have one form, on  a second form i have one drop down for selection what user want(eg. radio, checkbox,dropdown) and a label to that choice,so here can i add new HTML element(eg. radio, checkbox,dropdown) to current a file on form  submission???if Yes t

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but AJAX is probably the answer.

Comment: i feel your question is too confusing..

Comment: some code would be useful, what do you mean with *contains two fileds both have one form*

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, by the use of ajax.
not by the form post

Comment: ajax will replace previous element with new one

Comment: you can get current DOM element id and append to it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i got you right, your text is very confusing.

**Page #1**

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="addcheckbox" value="1"> Add a checkbox<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="adddropdown" value="1"> Add a dropdown<br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Page #2**

```
echo '<form [...]>';
if( $_POST['addcheckbox'] == 1) echo '<input type="checkbox" name="whatever" value="1"> checkbox';
if( $_POST['adddropdown'] == 1) echo '<select name="mydropdown">
<option value="Milk">Fresh Milk</option>
<option value="Cheese">Old Cheese</option>
<option value="Bread">Hot Bread</option>
</select>';
echo '</form>';
```

Comment: want new element on same page bro

Comment: Without a page refresh? Otherwise you can simply change the `action` to the same file and handle with it there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking.

You call a function onSubmit ([more here](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml)). And in that function you can dynamically add form elements via JavaScript if that is what you need.

Use `createElement` to create and `appendChild` to add the elemet where you want it.

More info [here](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/21/how-to-dynamically-add-form-elements-via-javascript/)

Comment: let me check with js ll get back to you

Comment: thanks i got something check this...http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamic-add-textbox-input-button-radio-element-html-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Do it through javascript, don't use form submit, it will take time.

First form

```
<div id="first_form">
    <form id=="firstform">
         <input type="text" />
         <input type="text" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Second form that will generate element

```
 <form id="secondform">
     <select id="choice" onchange="createElement(this.value);">
         <option value="radio">Radio</option>
         <option value="checkbox">checkbox</option>
         <option value="dropdown">dropdown</option>
     </select> 
 </form>
```

Javascript code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function createElement(element) {
       var html = '';
       if(element=='radio') {
          html = "<input type='radio' />";
       }
       else if(element=='checkbox') {
          html = "<input type='checkbox' />";
       }
       if(element=='dropdown') {
          html = "<select><option>abc</option></select>";
       }
      //use jquery
      $("#first_form").append(html);   
     }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery.It is the best wat to append element to the same page.